# re.findall within a list in python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a list as below.

```
sample_text = ['199.72.81.55 -- [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "Get /histpry/appollo/HTTP/1.0" 200 6245',
    'unicomp6.unicomp.net -- [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "Get /shuttle/countdown/HTTP/1.0" 200 3985', 
    '199.120.110.21 -- [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "Get /histpry/appollo/HTTP/1.0" 200 6245',
    'burger.letters.com -- [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "Get /shuttle/countdown/HTTP/1.0" 200 3985', 
    '205.172.11.25 -- [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "Get /histpry/appollo/HTTP/1.0" 200 6245']
```

I need to get all host names in a list. Expected result is as below.

```
['199.72.81.55', 'unicomp6.unicomp.net', '199.120.110.21', 'burger.letters.com', '205.172.11.25']
```

My code is:

```
for i in range(0, len(sample_text)):
    s=sample_text[i]
    host.append(re.findall('[\d]*[.][\d]*[.][\d]*[.][\d]*|[a-z0-9]*[.][a-z]*[.][a-z]*', s))
print(host)
```

My output:

```
[['199.72.81.55'], ['unicomp6.unicomp.net'], ['199.120.110.21'], ['burger.letters.com'], ['205.172.11.25']]
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You may want to quickly fix the formatting

Comment: It looks like you have a list of list and just want to make a 1D list?

Comment: @BryceRamgovind, it looks like he using wrong method which returns list and he just need to replace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily flatten `host`:

```
host = []
for i in range(0, len(sample_text)):
    s=sample_text[i]
    host += re.findall('[\d]*[.][\d]*[.][\d]*[.][\d]*|[a-z0-9]*[.][a-z]*[.][a-z]*', s)
print(host)
```

Output:

```
['199.72.81.55', 'unicomp6.unicomp.net', '199.120.110.21', 'burger.letters.com', '205.172.11.25']
```

Answer (score 4):

Without using regex you can just `str.split` on `'--'` and take the first part

```
>>> [i.split('--')[0].strip() for i in sample_text]
['199.72.81.55', 'unicomp6.unicomp.net', '199.120.110.21', 'burger.letters.com', '205.172.11.25']
```

Similar idea, but using regex

```
>>> import re
>>> [re.match(r'(.*) -- .*', i).group(1) for i in sample_text]
['199.72.81.55', 'unicomp6.unicomp.net', '199.120.110.21', 'burger.letters.com', '205.172.11.25']
```

In both cases you can use a list comprehension to replace your `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall()` returns a list of strings.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

`.append` will add the list as a single item to the new list.

Try:

`host.extend(`

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

I just used .extend instead of append which resolved the issue.

```
host.extend(re.findall('[\d]*[.][\d]*[.][\d]*[.][\d]*|[a-z0-9]*[.][a-z]* 
             [.][a-z]*', s))
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try something like this:

```
sum(host, [])
```

Comment: Using "hacks" to fix result produced by misusing method instead of replace this method is not the best advice.